# Choose function does't return 2 columns on Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I am trying to find a value by multiple conditions by `CHOOSE` command. But I get an error

> VLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range

Code:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2&B2,CHOOSE({1,2},'Revalue Percentage'!$A$2:$A$100&'Revalue Percentage'!$B$2:$B$100,'Revalue Percentage'!$C$2:$C$100),2,0)
```

I tried to change 2 to 1 like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2&B2,CHOOSE({1,2},'Revalue Percentage'!$A$2:$A$100&'Revalue Percentage'!$B$2:$B$100,'Revalue Percentage'!$C$2:$C$100),1,0)
```

It will return the first column. So I think choose function returned once column instead of 2 columns. Please tell my why it said error. I think it's google sheets' problem.

Comment: When you concatenate `Revalue Percentage'!$A$2:$A$100&'Revalue Percentage'!$B$2:$B$100` you end up with what is for all intents and purposes a single column of concatenated values. You cannot ask for the second column from a single column. The same goes for 'Revalue Percentage'!$C$2:$C$100. You probably need an index match pair and it might be better to pass control to the second range through iferror rather than an array formula choose.

Comment: actually I don't understand choose function. I need to return value from C column, would you tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this array formula¹,

```
=INDEX('Revalue Percentage'!$C$2:$C$100, MATCH(A2&B2, 'Revalue Percentage'!$A$2:$A$100&'Revalue Percentage'!$B$2:$B$100, 0))
```

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: yes it exact what I need. you saved my life :******